# Possible ways to handle long running process in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, memory-leaks

I'm trying to find best way to handle long running process in express app.
I have tried forks up till now. Is there any other good way to handle long running process in node.

Use Cases:

- read files, parse data and store to DB loops every 15 min.
- Polling : After x time period loop on approx 1000 records and read data from external api and save data.

I'm using setInterval for starting process again need solutions that can prevent memory leaks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron, create a cron worker with the interval.
This should address your both concerns.

1. You can spin up multiple cron workers.
2. Poll the external services in the cron and update the db, so the service layer always looks for the data in db instead of contacting 3rd party services.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks sathish That will work. But I'm interested to know what is going on on backend like if we have to do that manually.
Thanks